# How to set scope variable in isolate scope from link function

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I'm trying to set variable in isolate scope, but I can't access variable that I set in linked function in isolate scope and also I **can** access controller's variable.

```
app.directive('myDir', function($timeout) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        scope: {
            'propVar': '='
        },
        link: function(scope, elem) {
            console.log(elem)
            scope.linkVar = 'It works!' 
            console.log(scope);
        },
    }
})
```

I created plunker to show what I mean: http://plnkr.co/edit/lUBvIkF4fKXkEgujJpuU?p=preview

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It work's all as it should be.

1) If you define `'propVar' : '='` it means that your directive element has an attribute `prop-var`. This is not the case. If you would like to use the `prop` attribute you have to define your isolated scope in this way: `'propVar' : '=prop'`.

2) The child elements of your directive are bound to the controllers scope not to the directive scope. If you would like the the child elements to be part of your directive you may use a template in your directive:

```
app.directive('myDir', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        template: '<div><p>linkVar: {{ linkVar }}</p><p>propVar: {{ propVar }}</p><p>foo: {{ foo }}</p><button ng-click="foo=\'directive sucks\'">press me</button></div>',
        scope: {
            propVar: '=prop'
        },
        link: function(scope, elem) {
            console.log(elem)
            scope.linkVar = 'It works!' 
            console.log(scope);
        },
    }
})
```

see the modified PLUNKR: http://plnkr.co/edit/MHXXkmPdtfAUqtre4Fbg?p=preview

Comment: Yeah, but problem is that I don't want to use template. I want isolated scope for stuff in innerHTML of my div. Is it possible?

Comment: Hmm. It works with a little patch: template: function(tElement, tAttrs) { return tElement[0].innerHTML; }
But thanks for the answer ;)